# Mapping sender as first recipient with DocuSign for Salesforce custom button

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have what should be a very simple straightforward custom button with the following goals.

- Recipient 1 is the sender. (aka the Salesforce user pressing the button)
- Recipient 2 is the client.

The button code is as follows:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}

//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********// 
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';
//*************************************************//

DST = '--- TEMPLATE GUID REMOVED FOR EXAMPLE CODE ---';
CCRM = 'Internal~Internal;Client~Client';
CCTM = 'Internal~Signer;Client~Signer';
CRL = 'Email~{!User.Email};LastName~{!User.LastName};Role~Internal;Email~{!Lead.Email};LastName~{!Lead.LastName};Role~Client;';
alert(CRL);
CES = 'Test Email Subject';

//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0 &SourceID={!Lead.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+" &CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+" &DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+" &SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+" &SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES; 
//*******************************************//
```

I have ensured that the roles align between the DocuSign template, Salesforce, and the CCRM & CCTM variables. (See the following two images.)

**DocuSign Roles**

...............[image]

**Salesforce Roles**

...............[image]

`alert(CRL)` produces the following output which shows me the variable `CRL` is getting the right information.

[image]

However, at the next page the first recipient is dropped and the 2nd recipient is labeled as the first recipient with the role "Client". (See image below.)

[image]

The documentation [here](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/dfs-admin-guide-custom-button-configuration) specifies the following..

> The RoutingOrder is ignored if the “DocuSign Template” option is
>   added.

Although, adding the routing order attribute to the `CRL` variable produces the same output as above except the 2nd recipient is properly labeled as recipient 2 with the first recipient omitted.

What do I need to do to properly map the Salesforce user pressing the custom button as the 1st recipient of the document with the role "Internal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research I had a minor syntax error in the following line.

```
CRL = 'Email~{!User.Email};LastName~{!User.LastName};Role~Internal;Email~{!Lead.Email};LastName~{!Lead.LastName};Role~Client;';
```

Recipients in the Custom Recipients List must be separated by a comma.

If you look closely enough I accidentally used a semicolon for the separation of recipients.

The corrected line of code is:

```
CRL = 'Email~{!User.Email};LastName~{!User.LastName};Role~Internal,Email~{!Lead.Email};LastName~{!Lead.LastName};Role~Client;';
```

Comment: Please mark your question as answered/resolved. Thanks for sharing your experience.